Reproduce Slow SQL Execution Plan in Local
I have a .NET application where a menu is clicked to get user data and the data comes running a SP in the background. The SP has a complex query which returns the number of data on date filtering. Now the filter initially populates data for the last three months after modification, previously it was around 12 months. Now for some users, this SP takes 30 to 40 secs and sometimes 20 secs. To figure out the issue, I did some R & D for a while and depending upon those, did some initial analysis. Below is the SP that I run in production:
exec [sp_GetUserData] @Id=1002; 

I followed this link to have idea what could be the cause - SQL Query slow in .NET application where an answer by Daniel Renshaw states:

In my experience the usual reason why a query runs fast in SSMS but slow from .NET is due to differences in the connection's SET-tings. When a connection is opened by either SSMS or SqlConnection, a bunch of SET commands are automatically issued to set up the execution environment. Unfortunately SSMS and SqlConnection have different SET defaults.
One common difference is SET ARITHABORT. Try issuing SET ARITHABORT ON as the first command from your .NET code.
SQL Profiler can be used to monitor which SET commands are issued by both SSMS and .NET so you can find other differences.

Keeping this aside, I followed one another tutorial - Reproducing SQL Server Query Execution Plan Performance Problems and tried to implement each step to reproduce the same in the local. Now for SET commands, both the links says should be maintained. From SQL Profiler, I copied the procedure from text data column and executed in the local to see the differences and both local as well as production database have same amount of data. But in local, the SP runs faster in 1 or 2 secs.
Do I have to configure anything explicitly for the SET commands or simply copying the procedure from the profiler would do?
From the second link, the following steps that I followed:

In SQL Profiler, select the Standard Template.
Start the trace with the default settings. The very first rows that
will appear correspond to the ExistingConnection event class. Each
row corresponds to a different database connection.
Select the row that corresponds to the connection being used by the
user's application and copy the TextData column to your query window.
The text data column for the ExistingConnection event class contains
the required SET commands to setup any connection the same way as the
selected connection.
Execute the user's stored procedure to reproduce the problem. Now you
will get the same execution plan that the user is getting and you can
start to analyze the execution plan.


The application uses Entity Framework for database connection.

As an FYI the prefix sp_ is reserved, by Microsoft, for Special / System Procedures. It should not be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?

So is this something related to the prefix and any idea for the SET commands? @Thom A

"So is this something related to the prefix" I didn't say that, I said that the prefix is reserved and should not be used (for user objects). What SET commands? All we have is EXEC; there's no SET there.

I meant is there any way that I can retrieve the SET commands from production profiler? When I see the live feed of the queries running in the profiler, any way to see the commands there as well? As some posts say, the performance issue could be due to that.

The query is not slow because the session settings are different. The same query can have different cached plans (including plans that may be suboptimal for other parameter values) because the cached plan is generated from initial parameter supplied when the proc was compiled and cached for reuse. See Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? for a thorough discussion.  Maybe your solution a simple as adding an OPTION(RECOMPILE) query hint to the problem query.

OPTION (RECOMPILE) should be added in C# or in the query itself?

The hint should be to the problem query in the proc. Although compilation costs will be higher since the query is compiled every execution, the runtime savings with the more efficient plans may outweigh those costs.

The runtime savings with the more efficient plans may outweigh those costs. - This would be maintained by the query engine, right?

It's not the SET options per se, that's a myth. It's just that it causes a fresh plan to be generated, which may be a poor plan. Forget you ever heard of SET options, and instead investigate why the poor plan is even appearing as an option. This is almost certainly caused by parameter sniffing. The server needs to choose between two bad plans, it sometimes chooses the worse one. Give it better options: no reasonable OLTP query should be taking longer than a couple seconds, 30sec is far too long. OPTION (RECOMPILE) is a patch, it won't fix the underlying query issues and may be worse.
